# Filtering the post_author outside the wordpress loop

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Mysql query set outside the wordpress loop, like the one below, which doesn't work. I would like to know how can I filter the sql results based on the author that created the post.

```
global $post;
$post_author = $post->post_author;
$sQuery = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT((post_date), '%M/%Y') 'Month',
       FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.post_author = '$post_author'
```

Any assistance is appreciate it.

Thank you,

Comment: please do post the schema an sample records.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. my problem is not getting the results from the table, is filtering them by post author on wordpress

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra comma after `'Month'`.  Try this:

```
$post_author = $post->post_author;
$sQuery = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT((post_date), '%M/%Y') 'Month' FROM wp_9691posts p WHERE p.post_author = '$post_author'";
```

I also added the final `"` to enclose the query string.